# Why does my python code work after coding but not on boot?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I've coded a script on python that takes a picture with my raspi camera whenever I push a button. These are the codes

```
from gpiozero import Button
from time import sleep
From picamera import PiCamera

button = Button(2)
camera = PiCamera()

while True:
    button.wait_for_press()
    camera.start_preview()
    sleep(3)
    camera.stop_preview()
    camera.capture(‘imagex.jpg’)
```

I then went into terminal to make my raspberry pi to run this code on boot.
This is what I did in Terminal

1. sudo nano /etc/profile
2. Scrolled to bottom and added "sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/takepicture.py &" (my python script is in Desktop and I included & so the script runs in the background.

The issue I am facing here is, while the code runs perfectly after I coded it. After I rebooted the raspberry pi, it just doesn't take any pictures at all! I went back into the python script and tried running it, it just returns me these errors.

```
mmal : mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV):ENOSPC
mmal : mmal_port_enable: failed to enable connected port (vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV))0x1fecfa0 (ENOSPC)
mmal : mmal_connection_enable: output port couldn't be enabled
Backend terminated (returncode: -11)
Fatal Python error : Segmentation fault
```

What did I do wrong here? I am unable to debug this issue.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with the GPU when `/etc/profile` is executed. Check [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=44491). And [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247738/why-is-etc-profile-not-invoked-for-non-login-shells) for more about `profile`. So please try `bashrc` instead or start the script with the autostart.

Comment: Maybe `/etc/profile` is executed before the loading of the camera, so it will fail. try `bashrc` like advised.

Comment: @Kampi I went through the links provided. I dont exactly understand the thread in the forum. I tried replacing the following "sudo python /home/pi/takepicture.py &" from /etc/profile to /etc/bash/bash.rc and I'm receiving the same error message on Terminal. What can I do to solve the GPU problem?

Comment: I've managed to solve the issue, to whoever is facing the same issue. It is because placing the command in /etc/profile causes the script to boot way too early at boot, before the camera component can be connected.

What you need to do is 
1. in terminal, type sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc
2. at the bottom of the script, add 
echo Running at boot
sudo python /home/pi/myscript.py (depends where your file is located in)
3. sudo reboot.

What this does is launching the script slightly later after the camera component has been connected and detected by the raspi. Should work perfectly fine.